# Why are there naked ancient statues?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome

I don't know a lot of Roman history, but I noticed in some of their statues, naked people. Their sexual organs are shown and obivious to people. Here's a simple google [search](https://www.google.com.lb/search?q=roman%20status&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.51156542,d.Yms,pv.xjs.s.en_US._-554IbEZc0.O&biw=1024&bih=612&wrapid=tlif137752707753551&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=ar&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=JmUbUujPHsSPtQaX-IFg#fp=1e51b2f692e9b700&hl=ar&q=roman+statues&spell=1&tbm=isch&um=1).

Was it normal back then for citizens to show their sexual organs? Was it a symbol of strength? Could someone walk naked in the summer?

Comment: [Here's](http://www.livescience.com/4315-ancient-greeks-nude.html) a good place to start.

Comment: they simply weren't the hypocritical prudes that we are and showed the body like it really is rather than a version with the bits some zealots get excited about cut off to "protect vulnerable souls from temptation".

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/2259/1401)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace That is a good point, for this question to be worthwhile (rather than being flagged as a duplicate) it will need to address significantly different reasons for non-male nudity *or* address reasons for nudity in general (equally applicable in male and non-male instances).

Answer (score -1):

No, they did not walk naked, they just created these statues.

The Roman statues follow the tradition of the Greeks.

Comment: I have to downvote this: No substantiation whatsoever - not even a wiki! This kind of thing might be appropriate for a comment - a hunch you have without evidence - sometimes we see that. But this by no means qualifies as an answer.